# Copy backup Solr index between Production Solr Cloulds

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper

I have 2 Solr clouds setup on production servers (UNIX boxes). Each of them has 8 Solr nodes (tomcat servers) and 3 zookeeper nodes. Each collection is spread into 8 shards with 2 replicas. I took  snapshot backup for one collection on one cloud using the Solr replication command -  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Backing+Up.
The backups are formed in the form shardXReplicaY. I get total 16 backup index folders (8 shards * 2 replicas) in my one cloud.

I have an issue when I try to copy it to the other cloud. I'm copied the lucene index files into the same shard and replica's index folder(eg: solr/multicore/Collection1_shard4_replica2/data/index) on the OTHER cloud's node. I did it for all the 16 shards and replicas.

I started the zookeeper boxes successfully.But, as soon as I started the tomcat on these boxes,all those index files, the I had just copied, got deleted and they are replaced by some empty files that Solr createg like this :[image: the empty files Solr creates]

I'm not sure what these files are. I tried to remove these files one by one while the serve was down and even removing all of them, before copying my index files, but the same thing happens again. At the node's server start up all the index file in the /data/index directory are deleted  and are replaced with these three files.  What I think is happening is, it is purging the existing data on start up and creating an empty collection. My numDocs is 0 now. How can I force Solr to read the data from the /data/index directory and not delete it! ? Or is there some other way to copy the collection level data between Solr clouds ?? I'm okay with cold backups too.

TIA
Sagar